# mod_rewrite works on localhost but not when upload into server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wrote a code to redirect people who ask for foo.html to the page bar.html instead. 
my .htaccess file is as below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo.html$ bar.html
```

It works on localhost.But gets the following error when runs in web server.

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Please provide .conf on server. Are you enable rewrite module on server?

Comment: What's with all the tags? Is it a windows server and what does php have to do with it?

Comment: #vanadium23 can you please suggest how to enable rewrite module on server?

Comment: 1) is page really present? what about www.example.com/bar.html ? 2)Test case of filenames

Comment: both foo.html and bar.html presents in www.example.com directory.

Comment: If you have really asked www.example.com/bar.html  and watched any output, the only my suggestion is that bar - php scrit which generate 404 error, when called  by redirect

Comment: both bar.html and foo.html displays in the right way.
I wrote .htaccess code to redirect people who ask for foo.html to the page bar.html.Which works perfect in localhost but not when upload into server.the error mentioned in question